# pgSQL: select first occurrence of the number inside a string

Tags: postgresql

String contains numeric and alphabetic data. what is the way to pick up only number? for example:
for the string "abc-123a-66" select should return "123"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [regexp_matches](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html)

```
CREATE table foo (
test VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES('abc-123a-66');

SELECT (regexp_matches(test, '\d+'))[1] FROM foo;
```

Example at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c51a/1)

Comment: regexp_matches(test, '\d+') returns an array though, OP was asking for the actual number.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL this can be done with:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(regexp_replace(whatever_columnn,'\D*',''),'\d+') FROM whatever_table;
```

The first function (`regexp_replace`) deletes every non digit from the beginning of the string, the second (`regexp_matches`) extracts one or more occurrences of any digit from the output of the first function.

Comment: it works, but data id returned surrounded by brackets. i'd like to get integers. I want to check if number is odd or even using mode function.

Comment: In that case put the regexp_matches call in brackets and then access the returned values by the indices. For example: regexp_matches(regexp_replace(whatever_column,'\D*',''),'\d+'))[1]